# Замена строки в файле

Tags: python, файлы, строки, replace

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей.

Есть файл **"primer.txt"**, в нем есть строка (номер строки динамический, так как  в него постоянно записываются данные)

```
"StrokaNaZamenu=123"
```

Значение после равно тоже динамическое.
Нужно в этом файле заменить или цифры (например на 999) или можно всю строку путем замены старой на новую **"StrokaNaZamenu="+"999".**

Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Нормальный метод замены -- переписать в другой файл, старый удалить, новый переименовать в старый. Вам такой вариант подойдёт? (1).

Почему обязательно python? (2)

Comment: Если в файле все значения вида:

    param=value

то можно использовать (ConfigParser)[http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html]

Прочитали конфиг, заменили значение, сохранили конфиг.

Если у вас нету секций, то их можно легко эмулировать

Comment: а где то так

    s = "StrokaNaZamenu=123"
    arr = s.split('=',2)
    # arr - теперь массив с двух элементов.
    new_s = arr[0] + '=' + 999

Comment: Нормальный метод замены -- переписать в другой файл, старый удалить, новый переименовать в старый. Вам такой вариант подойдёт? (1).

Да, так тоже подойдет.

Comment: @drenadan ну как шаблон (проверки вставить по вкусу):

    import os, tempfile
    a = "StrokaNaZamenu=999"
    a1 = a.split('=')
    fn = "primer.txt"
    f = open(fn, 'rt')
    f1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)
    for s in f:
      s1 = s.rstrip('\n')
      if a1[0] in s1: print(a, file=f1)
      else: print (s1, file=f1)
    f.close()
    st_mode = os.stat(fn)
    f1.close()
    os.remove(fn)
    os.rename(f1.name, fn)
    os.chmod(fn, st_mode.st_mode)

На sed  это выглядит гораздо короче и красивей.